# Non-ASCII characters use Times New Roman font in Outlook until default font is manually re-applied

Tags: microsoft-outlook, fonts, non-ascii

The following font issue appears in any HTML message body in Outlook (e-mail, appointment etc.), but Word and Excel don't have this problem. See this screen snippet from Outlook mail message body:

[image: Illustration of the problem]

- orange: problematic font
- green: font was corrected normally

How can I achieve that non-ASCII characters are produced with the default font right away?
(Office repair did not help.)

**Details:**

If I type a text with default settings, any normal text uses *Calibri (Body)* font which changes to *Times New Roman* for any non-ASCII character I type.
After if I select the entire text and re-apply *Calibri (Body)* manually, those non-ASCII characters switch to this default font normally. (Therefore, to make the message appear consistent, I need to re-apply the default font before sending any message with "špecial chařačters".)

Answer (score 0):

Right click the default Normal Style and choose "Modify". Set the font to Calibri (Body).

[image]

Mentioned in [this thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/cb9f23c8-170e-4f28-b938-544603637eee/default-font-settings-wont-hold-each-time-i-restart-outlook?forum=outlook) you can also try following steps:

1. Close Word and Outlook
2. Go to C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates
3. Rename NormalEmail.dotm to NormalEmail.old
4. Open Outlook and change your default font
5. Close and open Outlook again.